# How to create auto table (html tag) in vim editor? like: table>tr*10>td*4 than press tab in PhpStorm

Tags: html, vim, html-table, phpstorm

We can create this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just by typing:

```
table>tr*4>td*4
```

then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in PhpStorm.

But, can we do this in vim editor? How? Should we add something in `.vimrc` or...?

Comment: Well, PHPStorm uses a built-in plugin for that called Emmet maybe you could look it up?

Comment: It's called Emmet and should be available to vim as well. https://emmet.io/

Comment: @romainl ok ty:)

Comment: @LazyOne ty... i ll try that... thats insane:) i have no idea what other things we can do with this  awesome editor

Comment: @Sss lots of things :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Vim doesn't support that out-of-the-box.

Fortunately, `Vim is a highly configurable text editor` and have a lot of plugins for doing almost anything.

The one you could try for doing that "expand" is [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim)